# A data set for click through rate

Tags: data-request

I'm particularly looking for the dataset in the article
[Predicting Clicks:
Estimating the Click-Through Rate for New Ads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/predictingclicks.pdf)

Does anyone know if this data set is available?

(Note: I checked all the references and didn't find the data source. I contacted the authors and am waiting for their reply).

Comment: the data in the article, or the data in the citations? have you checked them out?

Comment: Hi Albert I checked all the references and  as far as I noticed didn't find the data source. I contacted the authors and waiting for their reply.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the data set you asked for, but kaggle has a relevant one for CTR:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/avazu-ctr-prediction/data